# iOS: Loading random UIImageView when running iOS simulator

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I have two images, "image1" and "image2" . What I want to do is that whenever I open the iOS simulator it will load one of these images at random. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you `ViewDidLoad` or wherever you want you want your `imageView` to be:

```
//create image array
NSArray *imagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"], nil];
//random number
int r = arc4random() % [imagesArray count];

//create imageview
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
[imageView setImage:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:r]];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: It works, thank you! but is there a way to create the image with the UIBuilder?

Comment: Changing the imageView height and width is already in the above code: UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT)];

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, i figured it out, but is there a way to create the image with the UIBuilder?

Comment: This tutorial should help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUO3VGFdkfg and please accept the answer if it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

@interface YourViewController()
//Add an Image View to the storyboard on your view controller, then add outlet to your code for that image view
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *anImageView;
@end

@implementation YourViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    //random number 0 or 1
    int r = arc4random() % 2;
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"];
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"];

    if (r == 0){
        //if random number is 0, set image view to image1 when view loads
        [self.anImageView setImage:image1];
    }
    else{
        //if random number is 1, set image view to image2 when view loads
        [self.anImageView setImage:image2];
    }
 }
@end
```